# В операторе if переход на другую страницу

Tags: php

Как в PHP перейти на другую страницу? Через require или fopen?

```
if ($row_login['password'] != $_POST['password'])
    echo 'Не верный пароль';
else {    
    require('page.php')
}
```

Comment: Делайте `header("Location: page.php"); exit;`, если я правильно вопрос понял. После Location либо полный адрес (`http://...`), либо страницу, относительно корня сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, в общем правильно, но можно и `include`-ом. А `fopen()`: можно и так, только геморроя и кода больше будет, ну типа так не делается.

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая функция [header](http://php.su/functions/?header).

> `header()` используется для отправки необработанных `HTTP`-шапок. См. в спецификации `HTTP/1.1` информацию о `HTTP headers`.

Comment: Правильный совет. Только автор должен помнить, что вызов хедера возможен только ДО вывода на экран любого текста.

Comment: Если вызов хедера возможен только ДО вывода на экран любого текста, то почему тогда у меня работает:
<html>
<body>
<p>text</p>
<?php
  
if (file_exists("index.php")) {
header("Location: index.php");
} else
header("Location:http://www.google.com");
exit();
?>
</body>>
</html


Answer (score 3):

Я обычно использую

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Это и правильнее, да и удобно.

Answer (score 2):

1. `header('Location: _URL_'); exit;`
2. `echo '<script>location.replace("_URL_");</script>'; exit;`

Второй вариант некошерный, но работает, когда надо перекинуть, не сохраняя страницу в истории. Или когда хидеры уже высланы.